# How to find the ideal kernel/algorithm arguments for classification methods?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, accord.net

I'm using multiclass SVM and deep learning-NN.
There are a lot of argument which I can adjust,
especially choosing the right kernel.
What is the best way to choose the ideal arguments?

Can it be done iteratively with any "target function minimazation algorithm" or it will take forever?

Comment: Hi. You should migrate your question to http://stats.stackexchange.com/. You can simply delete and ask this question there. This question is off-topic in stack overflow and will be probably closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's one of the most time consuming task in data mining projects. Finding the best argument(known as hyper parameters) are hard and also essential for data mining projects. So there are some solution for it(e.g [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org), witch is a machine learning lib for python, has [Grid Search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) to find good hyper parameters for algorithm such as SVM, also [here](https://github.com/rsteca/sklearn-deap), use Evolutionary algorithm to find the right hyper parameters for machine learning algorithm in scikit)

So for your question, I think it's better to write(or find) something like Scikit Grid Seaerch idea. Witch test a range of parameters(hyper parameters) in a specific algorithm and return best parameters according to test results.

For c# and accord frame work, it has a Grid Search to optimize the parameter: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_GridSearch_1.htm

Comment: Thanks, maybe you know any library that works on c# ?

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz, http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_GridSearch_1.htm